# Polymer <google-maps> data binding

Tags: google-maps, polymer, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I seem to be having an issue with data-binding to the google-map and google-map-marker elements with Polymer. If I try and use bindings as below the changes of `lati` and `long` do not propagate down to the map element. Any idea how to resolve the data-binding issue?

**map-element.dart**

```
@PolymerRegister('map-element')
class MapElement extends PolymerElement{

  // Variables
  @property double lati = -33.9258400;
  @property double long = 18.4232200;

  //Constructor
  MapElement.created() : super.created(){}

  @Listen('on-click')
  void updateLoc(Event aevent, Map details)
  {
    lati = -33.925;
    long = 19.0;
  }
```

**map-element.html**

```
<dom-module id="map-element">
  <template>
    <google-map latitude="[[lati]]" longitude="[[long]]" id="map1">
    </google-map>
    <paper-toolbar>
      <paper-button on-click="updateLoc">Focus</paper-button>
    </paper-toolbar>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Polymer API to update property values for Polymer to recognize changes

```
set('lati', -33.925);
set('long', 19.0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you point me to documentation to better understand how that works?

Comment: Here the list update methods are mentioned for Darr https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/properties#list-observation, otherwise see https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path